# accessing sqlite3 database through Jupyter notebook in VSCODE

Tags: python, sqlite, visual-studio-code

I can't figure out why I get an `OperationalError: unable to open database file` error when trying to open an already existing sqlite3 database from within VSCODE's jupyter notebook. I have no problem with accessing the same file when running the same code in an ipython terminal, or for that matter a script running in a shell. It is only when trying t to access through a jupyter notebook.

- I've checked the file permissions; for giggles, I set the file permissions to a+rw. No effect
- the encompassing directory is writable to everyone
- I can create a new file in the exact same directory

All I can think of is there is some un-writable cache directory that is trying to be used.

Any ideas? Thank you.

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-1.ipynb Cell 4' in <module>
----> 1 with sqlite3.connect('/home/me/file.db3') as conn:
      2     cur=conn.cursor()
      3     cur.execute('select count(*) from blah')
```

Comment: can python see the file via other methods in the notebook? for example, if you do `os.listdir('home/me/)`, does that list `file.db3`?

Comment: sure enough...same problem with os.listdir(). 
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted.

It must be something that vscode is doing. I've set the directory to chmod 777 and it still responds with PermissionError.

Answer (score 0):

finally figured this out - it was a macos security thingy. vscode needed to be authenticated in System Prefs / Security & Privacy. It's a mystery why certain directories were visible and others were not. Sometimes macos security overrides regular directory chmod settings.